# AngularJS - $http and notification service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple notification service on angularJS :

```
angular.module("my.services", [])
    .service("NotificationsService", function() {

        this.show  = function(message, options) {
            // display a notification
        };

        this.error = function(message) {
            this.show({...});
        }

        ...

    });
```

That would be fired when the server returns a "notifications" array embedded in the api :

```
{
    notifications: [{type: "error", message: "Error message"}, ...],
    data: [item1, item2, ...]
}
```

And now I would like to plug my service to $http, but I can't find a way to do so !...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [Response interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), and inject your `NotificationsService` into it:

```
angular.module("my.services", [], function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function (NotificationsService) {

        function notify ( response ) {
            angular.forEach(response.notifications, function ( obj ) {
                NotificationsService.show( obj );
            });
            return response;
        }

        return function ( promise ) {
            return promise.then(notify, notify);
        }
    });

});
```